# How do I add a library (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

I created a **Basic activity** in **Android Studio** and tried to run it on my **Physical Device** but while building the application is show an error under *The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a*:
`The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a`https://pastebin.com/x0PH4aQC

The *Build* error:
`Build:failed`https://pastebin.com/CTiV72eK

Comment: please post errors instead of links, and content of app's build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change `compileSdkVersion` in your project's app module `build.gradle` file to 31:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    ...
}
```